# AWS EBS not recognizng environment variables

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, deployment, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Laravel app via EBS but without the `.env` file.
Instead, i have entered all of the variables in the EBS configuration > Software tab.
I did a test just so I can check if they are properly read so I set `APP_ENV=stage` but when I ssh to the ec2 insteance created by EBS and I run the `php artisan env` command it shows `production` instead of `stage` which means the variables are not injected properly.

I tried rebuilding the environment several times but no clue. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

When you use EBS configuration > Software tab to define the environment variables, they take effect when the serve a request. they dont update the .env file.

when using CLI artisan commands, it will only follow the .env variables

Comment: So this means i still have to use the .env file. Didn't know this.

Comment: @NenadKaevik only for commands/crons unless crons are configured from EBS (to be tested)

Comment: I added my .env but now when i run php artisan migrate i get the following error ... which i think still has to do something with the variables ...
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: @NenadKaevik are you using 127.0.0.1 as DB_HOST by any chance?

Comment: 'host' => env('RDS_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('RDS_DB_NAME', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('RDS_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('RDS_PASSWORD', ''),

Comment: I was following this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html ... but when i replace the variables in database.php like mentioned, they are defaulted to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @NenadKaevik Change `127.0.0.1` by `localhost` and it should work